# Generate Erwin with Microstrategy 9+

Tags: reporting, data-warehouse, microstrategy, physical-design

I'm working on documentation of my reporting project and I need to include a graphic of the physical model. I know that there's a way to generate an erwin from Microstrategy with the entire model tables and their relations, but I'm a newbie and I don't have any idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can view all of the tables, their relationships, as well as attributes and their Parent/Child relationships using the Architect editor. You can access this by going into a project in developer, clicking schema drop-down, and selecting Architect.

Alternatively, as a shortcut, you can go into the same schema drop-down, select graphical view, and indicate whether you'd like to view Tables or Hierarchies (parent/child relationships between attributes). Either can be printed from the resulting screen.

Good luck!